# JPA equivalent for Hibernate filters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, jpa

Does an equivalent for the [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters) exist in the JPA? 
The following hibernate annotation can be for example used in order to define a filter:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="minLength", parameters=@ParamDef( name="minLength", type="integer" ) )
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="betweenLength", condition=":minLength <= length and :maxLength >= length"),
    @Filter(name="minLength", condition=":minLength <= length")
} )
public class Forest { ... }
```

I would like to use something equivalent from JPA in order to restrict read access to some entities. How it can be done using clean JPA, without Hibernate annotations?

I didn't find any serious and reliable solution. 
I analysed the "[JPA Security](http://jpasecurity.sourceforge.net/)" project. However, its home page was last updated two years ago, its last version is 0.4.0 and it doesn't seem to be a reliable solution. It's not a standard and it is not popular.

Other alternative in Hibernate which can be used in my case to restrict read access to an entity is the Hibernate Interceptor API - the following interface method can be implemented in order to append a SQL string which contains some additional conditions:

```
org.hibernate.Interceptor.onPrepareStatement(String sql)
```

or the following method can be overriden:

```
org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor.onPrepareStatement(String sql)
```

I found out that there are some JPA event callbacks and annotations, e.g. @PostLoad. However, none of these can be used in my case, because I need something to restrict access to entities based on some conditions (user role).

Anyone knows how it can be done using JPA standards?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are attempting to perform validations on entity objects.  You have a few options to accomplish this.

The first would be to use the *Java Validations API* and its associated validations.  This is the recommended approach with Java EE, of which JPA is a part.  For example, you could write your entity class as follows:

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 5, Max = 50)
  String name;
}
```

Now, every time you attempt to persist an instance of `Person`, the JPA provider will automatically validate the instance, provided there is a Java Validator on the classpath.  Validation errors will be thrown as runtime exceptions and can be used to rollback transactions.  It is also possible to invoke a validator manually, collect any validation errors and transform them into user-friendly messages if required.

The other (probably dirty) option is to use the JPA Event Listeners, perform validations and throw an exception if a validation fails.  This will terminate the JPA operation immediately and rollback any transactions.

Comment: I think this answer has nothing to do with the question. What @km asks is about filtering during reading data and you are refering to validate it during writing.

Comment: The gist of the answer is JPA events. JPA provides events related to reads as well (`@PreLoad` and `@PostLoad` so the answer is quite valid for reads as well.